# Updating with sql server query in c#

Tags: c#, sql-server

I'm trying to change the password for security.

If an user wants to change the password he needs to enter : old pass - new pass - new pass again

But my problem is on this point: Everything works well till it comes to update query
it gives me an error and does not run the query UPDATE.

Note : I just put a message box instead update query.It works.

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (newpasswordagain.Text != "" && passwordnow.Text != "" && newpassword.Text != "")
    {
        try
        {
            connection.Open();

            String sql = "select * from user where password = @pass";

            SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand(sql, connection);
            command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@pass", passwordnow.Text);

            var reader = command.ExecuteReader();

            reader.Read();
            var resultpass = reader["password"];
            int userid = Convert.ToInt32(reader["ID"]);

            if (resultpass!= DBNull.Value)
            {
                string aad = newpassword.Text;

                if (newpassword.Text == newpasswordagain.Text)
                {
                   String baskasq ="UPDATE user"+"SET password = @newpas"+"WHERE ID = @userid";

                   try
                   {
                       SqlCommand komut = new SqlCommand(baskasq, connection);
                       komut.Parameters.AddWithValue("@newpas", aad);
                       komut.Parameters.AddWithValue("@userid", userid);

                       komut.ExecuteNonQuery();
                   }
                   // hata kodu 1: 
                   // update fonksiyonu çalışmıyor
                   catch (Exception ee) 
                   {
                       System.Windows.Forms.MessageBox.Show("Hata oluştu ! HATA KODU : 1");
                       passwordnow.Text = "";
                       newpassword.Text = "";
                       newpasswordagain.Text = "";
                       passwordnow.Focus();
                       connection.Close();
                   }
               }
               else
               {
                   MessageBox.Show("please check whether you entered passwords the same or not.");
               }
          }
          else
          {
              MessageBox.Show("please enter password correctly.");
              connection.Close();
          }
      }
      catch (Exception ex)
      {
          //hata kodu 2
          // databaseten parola dönmüyor
          System.Windows.Forms.MessageBox.Show("Hata oluştu ! Hata Kodu : 2");
          passwordnow.Text = "";
          newpassword.Text = "";
          newpasswordagain.Text = "";
          passwordnow.Focus();
          connection.Close();                  
      }

      connection.Close();
  }
  else 
  {
      MessageBox.Show("Please do not leave blank textboxes.");
      connection.Close();
  }
}
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Can you post the error that you're getting?

Comment: Thanks a lot.Ivbeen fallowing this web site for a long time.Thx for your all efford.My error message is Hata olustu HATA KODU 1 @GregtheIncredulous

Comment: Passwords should **never** be stored as plaintext.

Comment: Ugur, go to HELP -> TOUR for site etiquette... and check that person's answer as the "solution" so others know what the final issue was in case someone else has similar issues, they too can see what may be their same issue/answer.

Comment: @DRapp im newbie so now i am trying to how.Thx for waking me up for this issue

Comment: Yup, just why the gentle mention as I think it should be a required reading for all new users to the site to understand better.

Answer (score 4):

Your update query required space or do like this.

```
String baskasq ="UPDATE [user] SET password=@newpas WHERE ID=@userid";
```

Let me explain you detail.

Your string look like this.

```
String baskasq ="UPDATE user"+"SET password=@newpas"+"WHERE ID=@userid";
```

So when you run your code it get combine and become like this.

```
String baskasq ="UPDATE userSET password=@newpasWHERE ID=@userid"; // Now this is not valid.
```

So either place extra space when you combine or place as single string.

```
String baskasq ="UPDATE [user] SET password=@newpas WHERE ID=@userid";
```

Also in above code I put bracket around user ( Like [user] instead of user ) because user is reserved keyword.

Above line that I said ealier has error too. But as you are reading from Reader and it does not have record so it throw exception before that line. Put if condition.

```
 if (reader.Read())
            {
                var resultpass = reader["password"];
                int userid = Convert.ToInt32(reader["ID"]);
                if (resultpass != DBNull.Value)
                {

                    string aad = newpassword.Text;

                    if (newpassword.Text == newpasswordagain.Text)
                    {



                        String baskasq = "UPDATE user SET password=@newpas WHERE ID=@userid";
                        try
                        {
                            SqlCommand komut = new SqlCommand(baskasq, connection);
                            komut.Parameters.AddWithValue("@newpas", aad);
                            komut.Parameters.AddWithValue("@userid", userid);
                            komut.ExecuteNonQuery();
                        }
                        // hata kodu 1: 
                        // update fonksiyonu çalışmıyor
                        catch (Exception ee)
                        {
                            System.Windows.Forms.MessageBox.Show("Hata oluştu ! HATA KODU : 1");
                            passwordnow.Text = "";
                            newpassword.Text = "";
                            newpasswordagain.Text = "";
                            passwordnow.Focus();
                            connection.Close();
                        }
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        MessageBox.Show("please check whether you entered passwords the same or not.");
                    }



                }
                else
                {
                    MessageBox.Show("please enter password correctly.");
                    connection.Close();
                }
            }
```

Comment: You also have to use square bracket because user is reserved word so it create problem sometime.

Comment: unfortunately problem is still gaining and the error is still the same.

I think i will never be able to fix it with my own.Understood nothing at all. @dotnetstep

Comment: For further help on this please put what exception you got in catch.

Comment: Thank for your feedbacks but i got you already.I redefine my sql string.Nothings changed.My exception is "Hata Olustu ! HATA KODU : 1"

Comment: I think instead of your own message as exception try this System.Windows.Forms.MessageBox.Show("Hata oluştu ! HATA KODU : "+  ee.Message + ee.StackTrace); This give you detail of message.